# What does the `X` suffix mean in namespaces?

Tags: perl, perl-module

There are Perl module names like Moose and MooseX or DBI and DBIx or Catalyst and CatalystX or Mojo and MojoX or PPI and PPIx, etc.

What does the X suffix mean there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

eXtension, pretty much. It is just a convention to add features to a code base without stomping on the actual namespace or trespassing. DBIx means it's related to but not a part of [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI), for example.